# I want to change the increment settings

Tags: fullcalendar

The standard increments are set to 15 minutes. Is it possible to change this to 5m or even 1m?

And maybe not the view but the option to make appointments with custum length

Comment: The question is quite broad. Can you please give more context?

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `slotDuration` [(link doc)](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/slotDuration/) if you use v2 or `slotMinutes` [(link doc)](http://fullcalendar.io/docs1/agenda/slotMinutes/) for v1. Maybe you also have to use `defaultEventMinutes` [(link doc)](http://fullcalendar.io/docs1/agenda/defaultEventMinutes/) to v1 or `defaultTimedEventDuration` [(link doc)](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/defaultAllDayEventDuration/)

example for v1:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     ...
     slotMinutes: 5,
     defaultEventMinutes: 5,
     ...
 });
```

example v2:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     ...
     slotDuration: '00:05:00',
     defaultTimedEventDuration: '00:05:00',
     ...
 });
```